# Is correct this code in web.config for set custom membership

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config, membership

I want use custom membership and custom role providers. I have this classes:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
//override methods
}

public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
//override methods
}
```

I want set web.config, Is correct this code?

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomMembershipProvider, Login1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" connectionStringName="LoginDB1Entities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LoginDB1Entities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Because when I go to the ASP.NET Configuration, and Security tab, but get this message:

*There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: The method or operation is not implemented.*

Answer (score 1):

Issue here seems to be originating from your `connectionStringName` property.

make sure you define/add the connection string in your Web.config's `<connectionStrings>`   section

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="LoginDB1Entities" ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, if you ahve added already as above, then make sure you are using the correct settings.

First check where exactly your database is? Find out which instance of the SQL Server is the database of your application using. Modify the connection string to point to that instance.

Comment: Yes. I set this connection string in web.config

Comment: And are you sure you are using the correct settings like: Data Source, UserName, Password etc in your connectionStrings?? Also recompile, Rebuild the application and run again after that

Comment: my custom membership is working in site. but when I go to the ASP.NET Configuration, and Security tab, get message

Answer (score 0):

> The method or operation is not implemented

This is the message get if you throw `NotImplementedException` without any arguments.

The most obvious reason is that one of your custom providers has not implemented one of the expected methods.  If you can get a stack trace, you'll see which one.

**UPDATE**  in response to comment:

> my custom membership is working in site

The membership and role providers contain methods for two purposes:

- Methods needed at runtime for authentication (MembershipProvider) and authorization (RoleProvider).  For example, at runtime a RoleProvider only uses the methods `IsUserInRole` and `GetRolesForUser`.
- Methods needed to manage users (MembershipProvider), and roles / role membership (RoleProvider).  These methods are needed if you want to manage your provider's data store using the ASP.NET Configuration and Security tab.

It's perfectly valid to create a provider that only provides the runtime functionality - a so-called "readonly" provider, in which case you'll have to provide some other outside mechanism for managing the provider's data store.  For example, [WindowsTokenRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx) is a readonly provider.  But if you do this, you won't be able to manage your provider store using the ASP.NET Configuration and Security tab.

It appears you have failed to implement one or more of the management methods, and instead are throwing `NotImplementedException`.

Incidentally, `NotImplementedException` is not the best exception to throw for unsupported methods in a readonly provider.  It should only normally used to indicate a method has not yet been implemented in a version under development.

If you don't ever intend to implement the method, it's better to throw `NotSupportedException` - or in the case of a provider, perhaps a [ProviderException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerexception.aspx).

Comment: my custom membership is working in site. but when I go to the ASP.NET Configuration, and Security tab, get message. my custom membership is the problem?